# Unable to upload a file

Tags: 2007, error, file-upload

User 'X' is the site-collection owner. He tries to upload a 750kb file into a document library and gets the error:

> The server has aborted your upload.
>   The files selected may exceed the
>   server's upload size limit. If you are
>   transfering a large group of files,
>   try uploading fewer at a time.

However web application owners are able to upload the file. What would be the issue, any thoughts?

```
OS : XP
IE : 6
File is on : desktop
Special characters : no 
Upload size limit for a file – 5 MB
Site Quota template set – 50 MB
Used Site Quota – 10 MB
```

Comment: @Crazy: If you're still not able to resolve this, you might want to edit your question combining all of the additional clarifications/detail people have asked for in an update. This will make it easier for others to come along and resolve as well as bumping it to the top of the front page!

Comment: Sure, I am going to try few more steps and will update/edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any antivirus? Or perhaps an upload limit in IIS (not WSS)?

Comment: Anti-virus programs: Forefront & McAfee.

Farm Admins are able to upload the document, so do you think that it is due to the upload limit?

Comment: The IIS MetaBase.xml file entiry "AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed" can make any difference in uploading sharepoint 2007 files?

Comment: I found that AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed is only related to classic asp.

everything is seems to be fine from sharepoint server point of view, may it be an issue with client machine if so how to verify that?

Comment: McAfee enterprise 8.5 is installed on the client machine, will it be an issue.

Comment: Another option: IIS upload limit in web.config

http://www.sharepointboris.net/2009/02/upload-bug-in-moss-2007-windows-server-2008/

Comment: thanks for your help, however the user just trying to upload 750kb file and failed.

Answer (score 1):

What type of file is that? Check whether the particular type is blocked in Central Admin under Blocked File Types.

Comment: simple txt, doc, docx files.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions...

1. Can User 'X' upload other files to the site collection or is it just that particular 750kb file?
2. Can User 'X' upload the file to a different site collection?
3. Can you explain what you mean by 'Web Application owners'?
4. Can other users (not site collection admins) upload the file?

Comment: 1.Can User 'X' upload other files to the site collection or is it just that particular 750kb file?
Any file with more than 750kb

2.Can User 'X' upload the file to a different site collection?
No.

3.Can you explain what you mean by 'Web Application owners'?
User 'X' is a site-collection owner which is under a web-application and Web-application owners are able to perform this.

4.Can other users (not site collection admins) upload the file?
A particular team-members are not able to upload.

Particular set of people are facing this issue.

Comment: so it could be an issue with the users machine, what do you think?

Comment: Are you trying to upload via the normal Document Library upload page? Or is this through a third-party tool such as the Telerik controls? Some third-party tools have their own limits set in separate configs.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear on "web application owners'. As far as I know there's no such thing. Do you mean Farm Administrators? If not, how do you make someone a web application owner? Or are you referring to giving someone access through the "Policy for web application" in Central Admin?

Comment: How and from where can these 'web application owners' upload the file succesfuly?

Comment: Using standard sharepoint upload page they are able to upload into a sharepoint 2007 document library.

Comment: McAfee enterprise 8.5 is installed on the client machine, will it be an issue.

Comment: @Karthikeyan I know this issue is reaaaally old, but I am facing the same as yours on a SP2013 farm. Any chance you remember what get you out of this "can upload 100Mo file with File Explorer but can not do it through web" issue , please ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

User is able to upload (copy & paste) the file from Explorer view but not through normal way.

What could be the issue?